# Using Infopath Form for a Project Request

Tags: infopath, form, approval

I am trying to create an Infopath form and corresponding Nintex workflow for colleagues to use when requesting a new project but am stuck. The idea being a colleague can use the form when they want something done, the manager can review/assign an owner/priority level/completion date then route the request to the owner to work on. Once the owner is done, they would fill out some more information on the form and it would be closed out. The basic workflow would be:

1. Colleague completes form
2. Manager reviews form and fills in additional information including owner and priority
3. Owner works on project then updates form to complete when finished

I need a form that allows for some sections to completed from the beginning but then other sections to be filled out at a later date and don't know how to set that up. Any help provided would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do that in InfoPath, you can define multiple "Views" ([see support article here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-89677734-2a77-47fa-8c04-d83fd24f18c2)).  Each view can be configured with whichever fields you want to be presented at the various stages of the workflow.  Then, see the section in that support link titled "Display a view using a form load rule" to specify which View should be displayed based on existing metadata.

This way you only have to manage a single InfoPath Form, but different users can see different variations based on your rules.  If you have "privileged" users who are allowed to see multiple stages, you can enable the "Switch Views" button just for certain user Groups.

Comment: That is best way forward I used that approach successfully on many projects.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the form. You can have multiple InfoPath forms that you can define a list with different Content-Types in it with the required fields. For each content type you can create a different InfoPath form.

When Step 1 is done, just switch the Content-Type (you can achieve this with a SP Workflow for example) so the next form (Step 2) will be active. After submit of the form again switch the Content-Type etc. etc.