# Can I send an email that switches views on a Infopath form?

Tags: approval

Is there a way that I can use views to email the approver the "internal use only" view in which he can add his approval/denial and comments? So the colleague completes the "Editable" view, hits submit which sends an email to the approver in "internal use only view" where he can add his portion then hit submit to close out the item?

See previous post for more context. [Using Infopath Form for a Project Request](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275713/using-infopath-form-for-a-project-request)

Answer (score 1):

You can add &DefaultView=ViewName to query string of the url.

Example: `https://mysharepointserver/sites/mytestsite/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XSNLocation=MyPathToXSFile&ID=1&IsDlg=2&DefaultView=Approval`

You can also default to a specify view based on metadata or other criteria by building a [Form Load Rule](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-89677734-2a77-47fa-8c04-d83fd24f18c2#__toc259533881).